# Passing inline function to inline function in F#

Tags: f#, inline

Is there any way to trick the compiler to take `inline` function A as a parameter of `inline` function B and create one big `inline` function with no calls?

Let's assume we have piece of code defines as below:

```
let inline action i = printfn "%d" i // printfn is for demo, originally some math
let inline iter lo hi func = for i = lo to hi do func i
iter 0 10 action
```

Usually, `inline` functions cannot be passed as function (they can, but they are not `inline` anymore, as they cannot be inlined into existing, already compiled function, so they get passed as "regular" collapsed function).

In this this case though, both function are `inline` so when `iter` gets expanded it is technically possible to inline `action` into it. It does not happen (generated IL definitely CALLS `action`) and JIT compiler doesn't seem to inline `action` either.

I wouldn't care but this `iter` contains some additional logic which needs to be hidden, but `action` is very short and whole thing is time critical. 
Anyway, imperative code which I would expect the `inline` version to be expanded to is 100% faster (takes 50% of the time).

```
for i = lo to hi do action i
```

Suggestions? F# 4.0 maybe? Some magic keywords?

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233229.aspx: "The inline specifier is a *hint* to the compiler that the function is small and that the code for the function can be integrated into the body of the caller." (Emphasis added.)  I don't think there's any way you can force the compiler to inline anything.

Comment: I suspect this would take some compiler improvements.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17912509/sometimes-f-doesnt-inline-functions-even-if-it-is-marked-inline

Comment: This is something I considered adding to the F# compiler but haven't got around to do it just yet.